# Compiling NOAA WAVEWATCH III got error in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 3d-modeling, modeling

I'm trying to compile the NOAA WW3 model and every time I try to execute `w3_make` file, I get this message:

```
               *****************************
              ***   WAVEWATCH III make      ***
                *****************************

 Exporting WWATCH3_ENV=/home/admon/WW3/model/bin/wwatch3.env
Main directory    : /home/admon/WW3/model
Scratch directory : /home/admon/WW3/model/tmp
Save source codes : yes
Save listings     : yes

[INFO] list of the programs selected : ww3_grid ww3_strt ww3_bound ww3_outf ww3_outp ww3_trck ww3_grib ww3_gint gx_outf gx_outp ww3_uprstr ww3_multi ww3_sbs1 libww3 ww3_gspl ww3_prep ww3_shel ww3_prnc ww3_ounf ww3_ounp ww3_bounc ww3_trnc
Making makefile ...

                *****************************
              ***   WAVEWATCH III makefile  ***
                *****************************

switch = /home/admon/WW3/model/bin/switch
   Checking all subroutines for modules (this may take a while) ...

Processing ww3_grid
---------------------
ad3 : processing constants 
mv: cannot stat 'constants.o': No such file or directory
ad3 : processing w3servmd 
mv: cannot stat 'w3servmd.o': No such file or directory
ad3 : processing w3gsrumd 
ad3 : processing w3arrymd 
mv: cannot stat 'w3arrymd.o': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'w3gsrumd.o': No such file or directory
ad3 : processing w3gdatmd 
mv: cannot stat 'w3gdatmd.o': No such file or directory
ad3 : processing w3odatmd 
ad3 : processing w3idatmd 
mv: cannot stat 'w3idatmd.o': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'w3odatmd.o': No such file or directory
ad3 : processing w3dispmd 
ad3 : processing w3nmlgridmd 
ad3 : processing w3timemd 
ad3 : processing w3adatmd 
mv: cannot stat 'w3dispmd.o': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'w3nmlgridmd.o': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'w3adatmd.o': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'w3timemd.o': No such file or directory
```

Then, I try to execute `w3_automake` file and it compiles just until it has to process the program `ww3_ounf` and shows up this message:

```
Processing ww3_ounf
---------------------
ad3 : processing ww3_ounf 
mv: cannot stat 'ww3_ounf.o': No such file or directory
      Linking ww3_ounf
      *** file ww3_ounf.o not found ***
*** Missing object files ***
makefile:431: recipe for target '/home/admon/WW3/model/exe/ww3_ounf' failed
make: *** [/home/admon/WW3/model/exe/ww3_ounf] Error 3
```

I have tried to reinstall a lot of times but I always get the error message. Any idea about what is happening?

EDIT: 14/11/2019
This is the result to print `nc-config --all`

```
This netCDF 4.4.1 has been built with the following features: 

  --cc        -> gcc
  --cflags    ->  -I/home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/include 
  --libs      -> 

  --has-c++   -> no
  --cxx       -> 
  --has-c++4  -> no
  --cxx4      -> 

  --fc        -> 
  --fflags    -> 
  --flibs     -> 
  --has-f90   -> no
  --has-f03   -> no

  --has-dap   -> no
  --has-nc2   -> yes
  --has-nc4   -> no
  --has-hdf5  -> no
  --has-hdf4  -> no
  --has-logging-> no
  --has-pnetcdf-> no
  --has-szlib -> 

  --prefix    -> /home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf
  --includedir-> /home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/include
  --version   -> netCDF 4.4.1
```

An this is the result to print `nf-config --all`

```
This netCDF-Fortran 4.4.4 has been built with the following features:

--cc        -> gcc
  --cflags    ->  -I/home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/include -I/home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/include

  --fc        -> gfortran
  --fflags    -> -I/home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/include
  --flibs     -> -L/home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/lib -lnetcdff -L/home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdf 
  --has-f90   -> no
  --has-f03   -> yes

  --has-nc2   -> yes
  --has-nc4   -> no

  --prefix    -> /home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf
  --includedir-> /home/admon/software/wrf/build_wrf/libraries/netcdf/include
  --version   -> netCDF-Fortran 4.4.4
```

I've been reading the user guide and it seems that nc4-api needs to be enabled but I don't know why when I install my libraries, it is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your switch file. Before running w3_automake, how did you setup you w3_setup?

```
w3_setup <main_dir> -c <comp> -s <switch>
```

Comment: Already setup my switch file. I used the following line:  `w3_setup model -c Gnu -s Ifremer2`

Comment: Oh apologies. The ww3_ounf issue seems to be part of the netCDF compile environment. Do you have fortran netCDF installed (run `nf-config --version` to check your version) and have WWATCH3_NETCDF in your environment variable?

See section 5.6 of the WW3 manual for more details.

Comment: My NetCDF-Fortran version is `4.4.4`. Then, when I try `nc-config --has-nc4` as suggested in the section 5.6, it says that nc4 is not enable.

Comment: Sorry @Erincon I'm not sure what is causing this. I have just tried to do an install on a new VM and now I am facing the same issue. I will try to get this working and will update this thread once I got it working. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Still the same. I've tried to reinstall several times all the libraries and the source code of WW3, and nothing changes. Any progress on your side?

Comment: No, no update on my side unfortunately. I will update you once I found out the root cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have traced the error you should put on the bashrc the exact location of the nc-config (not only directory but with the nc-config) so that ww3_prnc ww3_ounf ww3_ounp will be compiled

export NETCDF_CONFIG=$HOME/Library/bin/nc-config

Comment: Presumably just into the environment of the process running the configure script - or is there some reason it genuinely needs to go into one's `.bashrc`?

Answer (score -1):

also try this swithes

F90 NOGRB NC4 TRKNC NOPA LRB4 SHRD PR3 UQ FLX2 LN1 ST2 STAB2 NL1 BT1 DB1 MLIM TR0 BS0 IC0 REF0 XX0 WNT1 WNX1 CRT1 CRX1 IS0 O0 O1 O2 O3 O4 O5 O6 O7 O11 O14

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).